# Updating field value if it is null

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, exists

I think this is a simple question but I haven't touched in Oracle SQL for a while.

I want to update a table if a certain field value is null.

I'm not sure if I should use the "not exists" clause, and this is what I have so far:

```
update table_classroom
set cod_classroom = 'unknown'
where exists (select * from table_classroom where cod_classroom is null)
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
update table_classroom
set cod_classroom = 'unknown'
where cod_classroom is null
```

Comment: Thank you :) What if I also wanted to edit the modification_date field value on the same row? Should I just use
set cod_classroom = 'unknown', mod_date = sysdate ?

Comment: @madsantos . . . This asks the question that you asked.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a *new* question.  That said, you can just add more columns and values in the `set` clause.

Comment: @madsantos Yes, you can `set cod_classroom = 'unknown', mod_date = sysdate`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you also want to omit future entries where cod_classroom is null. If this is the case you don't need to update the column manually but you can include this in your alter statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_classroom MODIFY (cod_classroom NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown')
```

Comment: From 12c you might as well do this as `default on null 'unknown'`.